# pandas - dropna - what if arguments contradict?

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a pandas `DataFrame` `df`.

[image: pic003]

And let's say we call `df.dropna(how='all', thresh=0)` on it.

Isn't this set of arguments logically contradicting?
In fact when setting `how="all"`, isn't this redundant/contradicting
with any value we could specify for `thresh`?

Somehow I don't get how `thresh` and `how="all"` should work together?
It's just confusing from logical standpoint.

```
# Isn't this logically contradicting?
# Argument how='all' says "remove rows which have all values set to NA"
# Argument thresh=0 says "keep rows which have at least 0 non-NA values" i.e. "keep all rows"
# Seems the thresh=0 takes priority over how="all"

df.dropna(how='all', thresh=0)
```

*In fact if I may generalize this a bit... I come from Java. Java has method overloads. And I've always thought about this issue in Python. Since Python has no method overloads, it uses a single method name but multiple params usually with various default values. So each method in Python can easily turn into a **master method** representing a whole set of methods/procedures. But what if some sub-sets of argument values (like here in my example) just logically contradict to each other, or just don't make sense to be used together? In that case, what is a good (Python idiomatic) way to design such methods? The only solution I can think of is just to document such methods pedantically and just say: "OK, don't call this method with arguments **a** and **b** together, as it doesn't make sense, and/or the outcome may be unexpected".*

Answer (score 1):

The [source code of pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L5164) reads:

```
        if thresh is not None:
            mask = count >= thresh
        elif how == "any":
            mask = count == len(agg_obj._get_axis(agg_axis))
        elif how == "all":
            mask = count > 0
```

So `thresh` takes precedence over `how`.

Comment: Yeah, I could imagine that... even without reading the source code. My question is more general. Isn't this just confusing in general? Imagine we have 20 params to a method and some sub-sets of arguments simply locally contradict. How to design well such a method?

Comment: @peter.petrov Presumably one would specify either `thresh` or `how`, but not both.

Comment: Well, if you specify `how="any"` it makes perfect sense to use `thresh=k` too.

Comment: If `how='any'` then wouldn't you want to drop the row/column as long as there is a single null? the threshold for the number of non-null values becomes irrelevant in this case. If you specified `thresh=k` then there is no need to specify `how='any'` because that is the default argument.

Comment: And if `how='all'` it implies `thresh=1`, and specifying `thresh` does not make sense.

Comment: Well... `how='any'` to me means "use `any` i.e. disjunction semantics". And `how='all' ` means to me use conjunction semantics. Maybe I am misinterpreting this and that's why it makes sense to me.

Comment: the definition of `how` in this function is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). It may be slightly different to other general definitions in programming.

Comment: It's not different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction You are right maybe. Maybe simply... how and thresh are not supposed to be used together at all regardless if `how="all"` or `how="any"`. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to wiki. My logic background is not that great ;) apologies for that. But yeah, I think the docs could be improved indeed to say what shall not be used together.

Comment: Yeah, that's a general concern in Python, I think. That's because Python does not support method overloads. So each method can easily turn into a huge master method which implements N different procedures/algorithms, and which path/procedure is taken in the method body is controlled by the arguments passed in. But some sub-sets of the arguments set may not get along very well (as in my example). Anyway.

Comment: Normally exceptions are thrown if such cases happen. maybe a flaw in the code, I dont know

Comment: ... or just make one take priority over the other (as you found it happens in the source code here). There's no issue per se. We're just brainstorming in general.